# Is the socket option local in Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

If a socket option (eg. `SO_BROADCAST`, the socket is a TCP socket) is set by the system call `setsockopt()` at server side, is it possible to somehow retrieve it at client side (eg. `getsockopt()`)? In other words, is the socket option simply a local setting? (In contrast to "local", if a TCP option (eg. `Window Scale`) is set for a packet, it can be received naturally at the other side.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO_BROADCAST is not a TCP option.

Comment: @EJP I don't mean it's a TCP option.....

Comment: That's what your title says. You could always fix it.

Comment: @EJP Sorry for the ambiguity... I intend to mean the socket option, of which the socket is a TCP socket. I've removed the modifier TCP in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is straight no. Your local socket options are not discoverable on the other side, unless they directly change the protocol behavior. SO_BROADCAST doesn't change protocol behavior, and is not discoverable. On the other hand, TCP options altering protocol behavior (TCP_NODELAY, for example) are discoverable, at least in theory.

Comment: `TCP_NODELAY` controls how often and how much data the local kernel sends pending data at a time. It is not directly discoverable on the other side, as it does not alter the protocol itself. The receiver would have to use heuristics to analyze how often data is being received and guess if `TCP_NODELAY` is being used or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, this is exactly what I meant by 'in theory'. By monitoring patterns, someone, can make an educated guess.